# std::time_get - century?

Tags: c++, date, stl

Is there any way to tell `std::time_get get_date` what century it is? We deal with dates before 1900. Is there a better C++ date time library that would allow this? We have an in-house solution that deals with a few cultures, but `get_date` seems to handle all cultures so it is good as a last resort catch all...

Comment: Also, it's `std::get_time` not `std::time_get` or `std::get_date`.

Comment: @Rapptz OP probably refers to the facet function `std::time_get<T>::get_date()`, not to the I/O manipulator `std::get_time()`

Comment: @Cubbi Ah. I actually couldn't find that one at all when I tried searching but now I see it.

Comment: Negative time values?  Seriously, the positive number indicates time after the Epoch.  Search SO for "negative time_t'.

Comment: Question updated, meant to say before 1900...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a C++11 environment (at least in the std::lib implementation) you can make use of the new `std::get_time` manipulator:

```
template <class charT>
unspecified
get_time(struct tm* tmb, const charT* fmt);
```

For example:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int
main()
{
    std::istringstream infile("1799-03-03");
    std::tm tm = {0};
    infile >> std::get_time(&tm, "%Y-%m-%d");
    std::cout << tm.tm_year + 1900 << '\n';
}
```

This should output:

```
1799
```

The `%Y` conversion specifier is specified as "the year as a decimal number (e.g., 1997)."  When stored in a `std::tm` it will be the number of years past 1900, but the value is held by an `int`, accepting negatives.

The full set of conversion specifiers is specified by C++11 to be the set valid for the ISO/IEC 9945 function `strptime`.

If you're looking for a full-featured date library, `boost::datetime` that Rapptz mentioned is a good suggestion.

You are also welcome to use my personal date library which is a single header and single source that was proposed to the C++ committee and rejected.  I mention that as the source is still in namespace std::chrono (for proposal purposes), but if you use it, you should change the namespace.  [Here's](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/bloomington/date.html) the proposal which documents the library, and links to the single header and source implementation.

Translating the above example would look like:

```
#include "date"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int
main()
{
    std::istringstream infile("1799-03-03");
    std::chrono::date date;
    infile >> date;
    std::cout << date.year() << '\n';
}
```

which again outputs:

```
1799
```

As implemented this library also depends on the C++11 `std::get_time` manipulator for input, and includes options for varying the I/O conversion specifier (specified in the linked proposal).

Answer (score 3):

You can try looking at [Boost.Gregorian](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html)